# How to access sub array length inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array that I am trying to manipulate/merge similar entries. I push `-1` on the 3rd index of the arrays I am marking for delete. Here is a sample of `rowArray`:

```
[
   [44,16,0,-1],
   [44,16,1,-1],
   [44,16,0]
]
```

In my for-loop, I decrement through the array and if `rowArray[i][3]` exists I am trying to pop this array from the matrix. My problem is that in my `if` i'm always receiving a problem. When I use:

`if( rowArray[i][3] )..` or `if( rowArray[i][3] !== 'undefined')..` etc. then I receive a TypeError:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I have also tried using:

`if( rowArray[i].length  > 3 )` but this gives me the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```js
     rowArray = [ [44, 16, 0, -1], [44, 16, 1, -1], [44, 16, 0] ];
     for (var i = 1; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
       if (rowArray[parseInt(i - 1)][0] == rowArray[i][0] && rowArray[parseInt(i - 1)][1] == rowArray[i][1]) {
         rowArray[i][2] += parseFloat(rowArray[parseInt(i - 1)][2]);
         rowArray[parseInt(i - 1)][3] = -1;
       }
     }
     for (var i = rowArray.length; i >= 0; i--) {
       console.log(rowArray[i].length);
       if (rowArray[i][3] !== 'undefined') {
         rowArray.splice(i, 1);
       }
     }
```

Expected Output:

`[[44,16,1]]`

I should mention that I am using jQuery 3.4.0. Also open to better solutions to this problem (as always).

Comment: You don't need to use `parseInt(i - 1)`. It's already an integer.

Comment: please share your expected output

Comment: @Barmar I forgot to take that out from before, used it to be certain it wasn't making any problems.

Comment: Why do you need to mention the jQuery version? There's no jQuery calls anywhere in the code you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the second loop you are starting from the `rowArray.length` which is not right because the last item is `rowArray.length-1`. That's because the array starts from 0. So your second loop would be like this:

```
for (var i = rowArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   console.log(rowArray[i].length);
   if (rowArray[i][3] !== 'undefined') {
     rowArray.splice(i, 1);
   }
 }
```

Comment: `for (let i = rowArray.length; i--;)` ... i>=0 is pointless because 0 is already falsy. i-- returns i before it was changed. might as well just combine them.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce.you are just right but to bold the main problem and don't change anything else to show the solution I didn't want to change it more. Thanks for the mentioning.

Comment: you changed as much or more in your version than i did in mine. i only removed a few things.